# Apache2 server gather all the KeepAlive response together

Tags: apache, http, server, apache2, keep-alive

I have a server with Apache2 where my php runs. For my IoT application I send 5 requests via KeepAlive and I see that the server responds but at once as soon as it has fulfilled them all, getting 5 responses at once. I also have another larger server where there is Apache which is used as a proxy by nginx and in this one the responses come back as soon as they are ready not together.

I wanted to know if it is possible to reproduce this behavior, i.e. get them as soon as they are ready, also in the server with only Apache2?

(I've tried looking through Apache settings but can't find anything useful, even online I can't find anything.)

Thank you.